# BETWEEN query using JDBC with MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
public int getdata(String startDate, String endDate) {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    int id = 0;
    try {
        /*
         * SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
         * java.util.Date startDat = formatter.parse(startDate);
         * java.util.Date endDat = formatter.parse(endDate);
         */
        // ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from project.order Where PO_Date Between " + startDate + "' AND '" + endDate + "'");
        //ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from project.order where PO_Date between ? AND DATE_ADD( ?, INTERVAL 1 DAY) ");
        //ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order WHERE PO_Date between ? AND ?");
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order WHERE PO_Date >= ? AND PO_Date <= ?");
        //ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order WHERE PO_Date(now())>= ? AND PO_Date(now())<=?");  
        /*
         * ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(startDate)); ps.setDate(2, new
         * java.sql.Date(endDate.getTime()));
         */
        ps.setString(1, startDate);
        ps.setString(2, endDate);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        // System.out.println("value of rs "+rs);

        while (rs.next()) {
            ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(4));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(5));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(6));
            System.out.println("***************");
            // System.out.print(rs.getDate("endDate"));
            Iterator<String> itr = arrlist.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
        }
        rs.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
}
```

I tried to solve but I am getting out except last date means endDate which we give as a input.

I tried around 5 different queries but still I am getting the same.

Comment: Please tell us which database you are using.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the `DATE` type maps to the Java class `java.sql.Timestamp`.  So you should be working with this type to build your query, and not `java.util.Date`.  Here is code which generates the two timestamps you will need:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date startDate = formatter.parse(startDate);
java.util.Date endDate   = formatter.parse(endDate);

java.sql.Timestamp start = new Timestamp(startDate.getTime());
java.sql.Timestamp end   = new Timestamp(endDate.getTime());
```

Then use your first `BETWEEN` query to get your result:

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM project.order
                                             WHERE PO_Date BETWEEN ? AND ?");
ps.setTimestamp(1, start);
ps.setTimestamp(2, end)
```

Note here that I am using a parametrized `PreparedStatement`, which avoids (or at least greatly lessens) the possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: Please pay attention to what you are doing.  You still need to define the formatter as you were previously.

Comment: My last comment here: My code should run fine for you.  You need to sort things out to the point where you have strings containing valid dates, in some format.  Then just cut and paste the rest of what I have given you.

Comment: Yes?  Do you have a question?

Comment: The above code which is not working tell me the some other solution for my code.

Comment: What error do you get?  Telling me that it's not working doesn't let me help you.

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.  How have even verified that the code for query actually executed?

Comment: There might be no records stored. Add some records and try executing the above query.

Comment: @PopoFibo give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM project.order po
   WHERE po.PO_Date IS NOT NULL
     AND TO_DATE(PO_Date, 'DD/MM/RRRR') >=
         TO_DATE('17/02/2015', 'DD/MM/RRRR')
     AND TO_DATE(PO_Date, 'DD/MM/RRRR') <=
         TO_DATE('20/06/2015', 'DD/MM/RRRR');
```